# what is indexview give me example?

Tags: indexing, view, schemabinding

- explain the index view with a

--[tag-name](/questions/tagged/tag-name)-
real-time scenario

index view: when we create an index on a view that particular view is known as the index view.
there are some conditions to create an index view:
the view must be created with schema binding. when you have a  suitable view create clustered index on it. Avoid using joins.
index views are used in datawarehouse,and when we have large calculations.